# Dual Contouring - Normal Vectors of a Noise Function

Tags: math, graphics, 3d, xna, noise

I'm currently working on a voxel engine that utilizes dual contouring to give the terrain a more organic/real-life look.

If you're not familiar with dual contouring, basically I need to supply a density function to denote whether a specific point is air or solid (in my case, I'm utilizing 3D Simplex Noise) and I need to be able to provide the normal vector at any point on the 3D noise function.

Normally, when calculating normals for a triangle, I take the cross product of two of the vectors that constitute the triangle; in this case, should I just apply a small delta to the noise function to achieve the same effect?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a [simple approach](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~sunha/MCubes/html/index.html) using gradient for marching cubes algorithm (I'm working on a voxel engine too), but since you're still operating on a 3D grid and not directly on the triangles you could give it a try.

Comment: IF you have figured it out could you post your findings here? It would really help others who find this question in the future.

Comment: The thing I figured out was this method that he suggested. (take densities at deltas)

Comment: How exactly do you do that? At what deltas. Because this link is dead.

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  The link provided described using "Central Differencing"; here's another page on it: http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/numerical-methods/numerical-derivative/central-differences/

Answer (score 0):

You may compute the gradient function of the noise function as normal vector at a point on the iso-surface.

In 3D Perlin noise case, you may use [3D Perlin noise analytical derivative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297024/3d-perlin-noise-analytical-derivative/14141774#14141774).